# Открытие файлов в VS code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

При зажатой клавиши ctrl я кликаю по названию нужного мне файла и он открывается в новой вкладке. Но если я кликаю по другому файлу он не открывается в новой вкладке а заменяет его на тот который был открыт.

К примеру нужно открыть style.css и adaptiv.css в новой вкладке, кликаю по style он открывается, кликаю по adaptiv он открывается на месте style  А НУЖНО ЧТО БЫ РЯДОМ БЫЛ ОТКРЫТ И НЕ ЗАМЕНЯЛ.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2):

Оригинальный ответ https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38713405/open-files-always-in-a-new-tab

То есть по умолчанию в VS Code включен "Preview Mode". Это видно, когда по <kbd>Crtl</kbd>+<kbd>Click</kbd> открывается вкладка и название открытого файла выделено курсивом.

Чтобы отключить "Preview Mode" достаточно в настройках редактора добавить запись `"workbench.editor.enablePreview": false`

Так же советуют посмотреть более подробную информацию о "Preview Mode" по [ссылке](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/userinterface#_preview-mode)